# Get Lock Screen Preview?

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-wallpaper

Is there any way to get lock screen preview.

I am writing an application where required to set Wallpaper and then look how it will be look like. Since there is no API support to show lock screen preview so I am searching for other way.

1. Is there any way to lock screen with required wallpaper application wanted to set.
2. And on unlock device, reset existing wallpaper back.

Any suggestion here?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no preview but you can always lock your device from code:

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

Comment: hmm...so is there way to lock screen with live wallpaper which application will set and reset it back when device get unlocked...any suggestion ?

Comment: @Shubh, Your last comment doesn't make sense to me. Can you please rephrase your question.